# WordPress Zero Width Spaces in URL

Tags: wordpress

We have a user that has zero width spaces that are ending up at the end of URL's that he is copying and pasting from an outlook email client into his WordPress 4.9.4 site.  This doesn't happen on all of the sites, just some of them.  The issue is happening just on a standard page using the TinyMCE tools to create the link.

Is anyone aware of a way to easily have WordPress strip these out?  I don't know what the "correct" behavior is on these - but it certainly causes for some unique troubleshooting cases for the uneducated.

Another way to state this:  Is anyone aware what the "default" behavior is on WordPress TinyMCE with handling "zero width spaces"?  I have a user running into issues with them (not sure how they are getting there) and I've never seen this before.

Comment: it's unclear for me, what is your question about. can you provide example of what you have and what want to achieve?

Comment: I'm asking if anyone is aware what the "default" behavior is on WordPress TinyMCE with handling "zero width spaces" because I have a user running into issues with them (not sure how they are getting there) and I've never seen this before.